# Relation between Fermi surface and Fermi velocity

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, metals, fermi-energy

Is there a direct relation between the Fermi velocity and the Fermi surface? Can one reconstruct the Fermi surface if the full angular distribution of the Fermi velocity is known?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is roughly yes.

The fermi velocity is fully determined by the Fermi surface as follows:
$$
v_f(k) = \frac{1}{\hbar}\nabla_{\mathbf{k}}E(\mathbf{k}))|_{E = E_f}
$$